# Print Data in UITableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have need to print data in tableview using array
Example:-

```
var title = ["Java","C","C++"]
var value = [["Inheritance","Not available","Inheritance"],["Polymorphism","Not Available","Polymorphism"],["Static","Dynamic","Static"]]
```

How to print above data in UITableView in swift?

I have need show data in UITableView below define way:-

> -------------------- 
> Java  Inheritance 
>  C     Not available 
>  C++   Inheritance 
>  -------------------
>  Java  Polymorphism
>   
>  C     Not available 
>  C++   Polymorphism 
>   -------------------
>  Java  Static 
>  C     Dynamic
>  C++ 
>   Static

Comment: Please format your question. What code have you tried? What does it do wrong?

Comment: Please go and search about how to code UITableView and show your effort before asking question. After you understand how TableView work, what left is just a for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your data structure is the best for what you're trying to achieve - maybe this would be better

```
var sections = ["Inheritance", "Polymorphism", "Static"]
var language = ["Java","C","C++"]
var value = [["Not available","Inheritance"],["Not Available","Polymorphism"],["Dynamic","Static"]]
```

Assuming you have a simple UITableView, with a dynamic cell prototype `Cell`, then you need to define methods to return the number of sections, the number of rows in each section, the section headers, and finally the displayed cells.

You will probably want to make things looks prettier than this, but the code is simple (and doesn't need any for-loops)

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    return "\(language[0]) \(sections[section])"
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return language.count - 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

    cell?.textLabel!.text = "\(language[indexPath.row + 1])  \(value[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])"

    return cell!
}
```

[image: tableView]